# Gremlin dynamic update

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, graph-databases, gremlin-server

I  have graph I
want to calculating and updating degrees using gremlin on a big graph db with 10M nodes, what is the best way to do it I wasn't able to this in one query

Comment: Can you please add to the question an example of the type of query you have tried so far? Also, how did what you tried before fail (timeout, out of memory, etc.)?